# The difference between 'no naka' and 'no naka ni'

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に, relational-nouns

I understand that 'no naka' means 'in' or 'inside', but how does the meaning change when 'ni' is placed after it?
For example:

Hako no naka - inside the box.

Hako no naka *ni* - ???

Comment: Do you mean to ask what the に particle means in general (the place where something is), or specifically in this case?

Comment: I would translate 'hako no naka' as 'the inside of a/the box', not 'inside the box', as there is not enough context to even presume the box actually contains anything.

Comment: @MathieuBouville Specifically this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

箱{はこ}の中{なか} (hako no naka) simply means "the box's inside". It says nothing about the relationship between the inside of the box and another entity, e.g.

> 箱の中は広{ひろ}い。  (hako no naka wa hiroi.)
>   The inside of the box is spacious.

箱の中に (hako no naka ni) means "**in** the box's inside". It describes how another entity relates to the inside of the box, e.g.

> 箱の中**に**は大{おお}きな象{ぞう}がいる。(hako no naka ni wa ookina zou ga iru)
>   There's a large elephant inside the box.

Comment: Alright, so 'ni' is being used in a location sense here?

Comment: Yes. That's right.